# Google Chrome Cache - Mac OS X 10.8.5

Tags: mac, google-chrome, browser-cache

I'm having difficulty locating my Google Chrome Cache. I've searched and it says to go to ~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome, however I don't have a Google folder in Caches.

Any idea where I might be able to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in */Users/[your user name]/Library/Caches* or in */Library/Caches* ?
The Google Chrome Cache Folder is located in **/Users/[your user name]/Library/Caches**